# How to use eval() in compiled python file?

Tags: python, exe

I'm writing a tool in Python. I want to compile it in exe, but there are several uses of exec() and eval() in code, which is not supported in exe files.

Is there any possibility to dynamically evaluate python code in exe application?

Comment: Please be more explicit with _how_ you are compiling Python to an Exe. (Is it Cython, using Nuitka, py2exe?) There are differences between eac of these

Comment: I used auto-py-to-exe but if there is a way to do it with other way (i.e. using py2exe or cx-freeze) I'd accept other solutions

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `exec` or `eval`. They are inherently dangerous. Second, using those functions requires that the "compiled python file" include the entire python distribution; i.e., "python installation" as mentioned in the py2exe documentation. That isn't practical. Which is why you can't use those functions in a program "compiled" by such tools.

Even if you weren't trying to produce an executable from `auto-py-to-exe` or a similar tool you should not be using `exec` or `eval` in a production program. Those functions should only be used by tools like `ipython` to interactively explore the behavior of Python.